# Error when trying to add Decal Renderer Feature to URP renderer

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm trying to add a projection to a scene in my game. I followed [this guide](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.render-pipelines.universal@12.0/manual/urp-renderer-feature-how-to-add.html), but as soon as I attempt to add the Decal feature to my renderer all the gameobjects of the scene go black and I get these errors:

**Only universal renderer supports Decal renderer feature.**

and

**AssertionException: Assertion failure. Value was Null**

The [errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWqFq.png) keep repeating as well even though the game is not running. I assume the solution will be pretty simple, but haven't found any references of those errors yet. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue too. In my case, I was using the "URP 2D Renderer" when I should've been using the "URP Universal Renderer". [Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KMjw7.png).  Frustrating how the error is worded, because it's not very clear.

Comment: In my case I just found out I could use [sprite masks](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/class-SpriteMask.html), since my game is 2D. You might find them useful:.

Comment: Thanks! I never knew about this feature